# Typescript: code looks correct, compiler complains

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm starting to work with typescript. So far, the experience has been pretty positive.

This morning I'm taking over 2 existing projects, which are currently deployed in production and work. And thus compile. Both projects have the same tsconfig and nodejs config as far as I can tell. One of them compiled without any issue.

The other one is a different story. The compiler seems to stumble on valid code, and I have honestly no idea what's wrong.

For example, it fails on the first line of a file:

```
src/services/user-agent.service.ts:1:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.

1 import type { lookup } from 'useragent';
              ~

src/services/user-agent.service.ts:1:29 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 import type { lookup } from 'useragent';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have a limited knowledge of typescript, so maybe this is an old, deprecated way of writing code? I looked up the documentation, it looks ok to me.

Also this first line of a function:

```
src/handlers/my-handler.ts:15:31 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

15     const companyId = payload?.content?.customer?.id;
                                 ~

src/handlers/my-handler.ts:15:40 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

15     const companyId = payload?.content?.customer?.id;
                                          ~

src/handlers/my-handler.ts:15:50 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

15     const companyId = payload?.content?.customer?.id;
                                                    ~

src/handlers/my-handler.ts:15:53 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

15     const companyId = payload?.content?.customer?.id;
                                                       ~
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code to edit this code, and it doesn't complain about anything. Linters also pass.

Versions:

- nodejs: 10.24.0
- npm: 5.8.0
- typescript: 4.1.2
- tsc: 3.3.3333
- running in Debian on WSL2

I build with `npm run build`, which is using `tsc` behind the scenes. Again, this seems to work for one project, but not for the other, so there must be a difference, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Could you test the used tsc version by adding --version to your build script entry in the package.json?

Comment: Using version 3.3.3333

Comment: There's your problem. Try running npm ci

Comment: Wow. Yes indeed. Care elaborating on what happened?

Comment: The version in the package.json only defines which version should be used. If you just run npm i and a package-lock is present that version is used.

Comment: And your ide brings its own TS for linting so you can have a mismatch there

Comment: npm ci cleans your installed node_modules and makes sure the dependencies in your package.json are met correctly

Comment: That clears it up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Turns out I could even git reset the changes made to package-lock.json and it still compiles. Party time!

Comment: Now your lock is out of sync with your node_modules. Which is not good. You should commit a working lock

Comment: Sounds wrong indeed. But running `npm ci` again doesn't update the package-lock.json anymore. Any suggestion?

Comment: Delete it and try again